# How to pass parameters to pipeline during trigger run in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

As far as I know I can pass a parameters in manual run(trigger now). But how if I want to set the pipeline to autorun everyday, and be able to pass a parameter without entering the trigger now pipeline page?

Another question is that during the deign of my pipeline, I have set up few parameters and logic linked to it, like "if the parameter is null then run all table, it there is value, then only run that table", that is for user enter re-run for specific table. 
However, I noticed that the message "Parameters that are not provided a value will not be included in the trigger.", does that mean my logic in the pipeline cannot be setup this way if I want to trigger it automatically everyday?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could call a stored procedure to handle the logic that's my default these days

Answer (score 1):

Implementing heavy ADF logic can be difficult. You can set the default value for parameters but I assume those need to be set dynamically?

You could also use pipeline variables and an Activity at the beginning of your pipeline named "Set variable" and work with that using expressions to run your activity based on variables that are set with parameters?

In our project we did even something more complicated and we deploy and trigger a Pipeline once a week from Azure Devops. So not the ADF itself triggers the pipeline but AzureDevops scheduled run does.

Powershell:

```bsh
$parameters = @{
    "parameterName1" = $parameterValue
    "parameterName2" = $ParameterValue
}

Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName 
$ResourceGroupName -PipelineName $pipelineName -Parameter $parameters
```

With powershell you can implement any logic you really want at this point passing values to ADF.